# Why is DELETE method not allowed in simple API controller

Tags: rest, api, yii2

The basics work perfectly fine:

- GET index (/api/v1/pools)
- GET view (/api/v1/pools/1)
- POST create (/api/v1/pools)

But when I attempt to use DELETE delete (/api/v1/pools/1), I get the following message:

> Method Not Allowed
>
> The requested method DELETE is not allowed for the URL
>   /api/v1/pools/1.

I even defined checkAccess() as an empty method, but nothing seems to help.

**Setup**

Controller:

```
class PoolController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\models\Pool';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        // authenticate by using an access token passed in the username authentication header
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
....
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
        'controller' => ['v1/pool'],
    ],
]
....
```

**Requests & Responses**

*cURL DELETE request*

```
curl -X DELETE \
  https://###/api/v1/pools/1 \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic dHBDMEUxNWVscl8tNlF6OFVYSGV5V0NydVBwdEp5elM6' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

*cURL repsponse*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method DELETE is not allowed for the URL         
/api/v1/pools/1.</p>
</body></html>
```

*wget DELETE request*

```
wget --method DELETE 
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   
  --header 'Authorization: Basic dHBDMEUxNWVscl8tNlF6OFVYSGV5V0NydVBwdEp5elM6'   
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache'
  --output-document   - https://###/api/v1/pools/1
```

*wget DELETE reponse*

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 405 Method Not Allowed
2019-02-04 10:25:54 ERROR 405: Method Not Allowed.
```

For clarity, below the working request/response of another action (view) in the same controller is shown:

*cURL GET request*

```
curl -X GET \
  https://###/api/v1/pools/1 \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic dHBDMEUxNWVscl8tNlF6OFVYSGV5V0NydVBwdEp5elM6' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

*cURL GET response*

```
{"success":true,"data":{
    "id":1,
    "user_id":1,
    "name":"pool",
    ....
    "created_at":"2019-01-31 20:00:00"
}}
```

After further fiddling, I found out it will always return this message, even if I intentionally cause an internal error in the controller or the api main config. The working actions do indicate an internal error occurred. The request does not even show up in the debugger, only GET, POST and HEAD get that far.

Comment: Based on what you say, it should be working, how are you sending the request? CURL? Could you add the request to your question?

Comment: Last time I saw this error was because we were making an HTTP request instead an HTTPS, maybe this is the same situation.

Comment: I have included the request/response. It seems HTTPS was not the issue this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of wasted time I discovered the requests did not even show up in the api debugger (/api/debug/default/view) and a grep in the repo for the message returned nothing. Only then did I begin to expect the server.

The server is running Apache/2.4.35 (Unix) and in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd/extra/httpd-directories.conf there is a rule which blocks all but GET, HEAD and POST requests. I added PUT, PATCH, DELETE and OPTIONS.

```
<Directory /home>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNoExec +Includes
    AllowMethods GET HEAD POST PUT PATCH DELETE OPTIONS
</Directory>
```

Finally got it to work.

Comment: maybe you already know but just extra info if you don't know, if you try to send json with body, delete is not allowd. you can't use body with delete request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an xampp server running on windows 10.
Inspired by [ttdijkstra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110823/ttdijkstra)'s answer, I deep dove into my xampp installation folder in quest of `config` files. The only `config` file that had something similar was `...\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-userdir.conf` in which I added `DELETE` option as follows:

```
<Directory "C:/Users/*/My Documents/My Website">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS DELETE>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS DELETE>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

I was then able to perform `DELETE` requests normally. The same goes for any other request methods restricted by default by `Apache`.